# How to connect two CAN channels in vector canoe?

Tags: simulation, can-bus, canoe

I have 2 CAN channels assigned. Number one with generator, transmitter:
[image]

and Number 2 which will be receiver:
[image]

How to connect this channels to each other and make the communicate?

Comment: How would you connect them with hardware? You would need a node that is connected to both busses and relays the messages from one bus to the other and (potentially) vice-versa; aka a gateway. In CANoe you do it exactly in the same way.

Comment: You are right sir. The thing which was described in question does not makes much sense, but I wanted to learn how CANoe works etc. That's why I needed that